# No carga dll en modo mwindows (C++)

Tags: c++

Quiero cargar una dll desde un proceso *hidden* que he compilado con *-mwindows* en **g++** pero no carga pero si quito la flag *-mwindows* esta carga bien.

Aca el codigo:

> load_dll.cpp

```
HINSTANCE hGetProcIDDLL = LoadLibrary("MiLibreria");
f_funci funci = (f_funci)GetProcAddress(hGetProcIDDLL, "funci");
f (!funci) { /*...*/
```

Dll.cpp

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int funci() {
     MessageBoxA(NULL, "HOLA DESDE PLUGIN", "Plugin-msg", NULL);
     return 0;
}
```

linea completa del compilador
*g++ programa.cpp -o calcular.exe -std=c++11 -fno-rtti -fno-inline  -O3 -static -static-libstdc++ -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid  -mwindows*

Comment: ¿ Como has declarado tu función `main( )` ? Para programas GUI, has de usar el `WinMain( )` **exclusivo** de windows. `-mwindows` le indica al compilador que usas GUI, *ergo* deberías de usar `WinMain( )`

Comment: ¿Cuál es el valor de retorno de `LoadLibrary` cuando falla? ¿Has comprobado dicho valor de retorno y lo has buscado en la documentación?